# Apply height and width for the_content() inside youtube video tag

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails, embed

I am displaying video and content form this function `the_content()`
for this am using you-tube [embed] link. How can i give height and width ???

Also, I am using `the_post_thumbnail()` for image it to have size issues 
I've tried this

```
the_post_thumbnail('',array('width' => '240','height' => '170') );
```

but failed

Answer (score 0):

According to Codex [Embeds documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Embeds):

> It also allows you to set a maximum (but not fixed) width and height, like so: `[embed width="123" height="456"]...[/embed]`

For [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) you arguments usage seems wrong, `$size` is first argument and it doesn't come in that format ( `the_post_thumbnail( array( 240, 170 );` ).